# Code disappears in google online script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I've just started using Google script.

I quickly encountered a problem to which I have not yet found a solution.

The code disappears when writing or pasting a script longer than a page (for which a scroll down is needed).

Here is a screen shot of the problem:
[image: Screen shot]

This renders working on a script impossible.

Comment: This does not occur for me. I notice your console is right left however, and that the bar is scrolled fully to the left. Are you certain the code is not there if you scroll to the right? If you want to paste your sample code, I can try copy and pasting.

Comment: Thank you very much @HDCerberus, Changing the interface language back to English did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the interface language of Google to English fixed the problem.